# encapsulation in python list (want to use " instead of ')

Tags: python, list, mongodb

I have a list of users `users["pirates"]` and they're stored in the format `['pirate1','pirate2']`.
If I hand the list over to a def and query for it in MongoDB, it returns data based on the first index (e.g. pirate1) only. If I hand over a list in the format `["pirate1","pirate"]`, it returns data based on all the elements in the list. So I think there's something wrong with the encapsulation of the elements in the list. My question: can I change the encapsulation from ' to " without replacing every ' on every element with a loop manually?

Short Example:

```
aList = list()
# get pirate Stuff
# users["pirates"] is a list returned by a former query
# so e.g. users["pirates"][0] may be peter without any quotes
for pirate in users["pirates"]:
    aList.append(pirate)
    aVar = pirateDef(aList)
print(aVar)
```

the definition:

```
def pirateDef(inputList = list()):
# prepare query 
col = mongoConnect().MYCOL


# query for pirates Arrrr
pirates = col.find({ "_id" : {"$in" : inputList}}
                      ).sort("_id",1).limit(50)

# loop over users
userList = list()
for person in pirates:
    # do stuff that has nothing to do with the problem

       # append user to userlist
    userList.append(person)

return userList
```

If the given list has ' encapsulation it returns:

```
'pirates': [{'pirate': 'Arrr', '_id': 'blabla'}]
```

If capsulated with " it returns:

```
'pirates' : [{'_id': 'blabla', 'pirate' : 'Arrr'}, {'_id': 'blabla2', 'pirate' : 'cheers'}]
```

**EDIT:** I tried figuring out, that the problem has to be in the MongoDB query. The list is handed over to the Def correctly, but after querying pirates only consists of 1 element...

**EDIT 2:** Turned out the problem was wrong Input which did not match data in the DB (hate these kind of errors, cause they're simple yet hard to understand :-) ) I will delete this post in shame shortly..

**EDIT 3:** Damn.. can't delete :-(

Thanks for helping me

Codehai

Comment: Can you provide a sample program that demonstrates your error you are seeing? Please make it **short** and **complete**, and please provide the output you see when you run it, and the output you hope to see. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Comment: I am sorry, I added a more detailed sample

Comment: If you actually have a list of strings, the `'` or `"` isn't part of the string at all. So… what exactly do you mean by "' encapsulation"? Show us examples of the two types of lists.

Comment: The sample you provided is incomplete. Worse, it has syntax errors. Please copy-paste a short **actual program** that demonstrates the error you are seeing.

Comment: the problem is I am having the code on another Computer with different linebreak, but I'll try to log on with the system I have my code on to make my sample better.

Comment: Thanks. Having the actual program will help us to understand what you mean by "has `'` encapsulation" and hopefully will make the root problem easier to spot.

Comment: That "short example" doesn't actually do anything except make `aList = list(users["pirates"])` and set and ignore a variable named `aVar` over and over…

Comment: I tried to make things more clear, hopefully you understand the circumstances better now. Thanks in advance

Comment: I know the first list is useless, because I already have my list users["pirates"], but I tried that to make sure it is a list.

Comment: @Codehai: If you have some kind of sequence or iterable `foo`, and you want to make sure you have a list of the same items, just do `list(foo)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is your first listing:

```
aList = list()
# get pirate Stuff
# users["pirates"] is a list returned by a former query
# so e.g. users["pirates"][0] may be peter without any quotes
for pirate in users["pirates"]:
    aList.append(pirate)
    aVar = pirateDef(aList)
```

It is equivalent to:

```
aList = list(users["pirates"])
aVar = pirateDef(aList)
```

Except that your listing also calls `pirateDef` once per item in `users["pirates"]` with the intermediate values of `aList`.

Your second listing is syntactically incorrect, because it is incorrectly indented. I assume you mean for everything in the listing to be indented such that it is part of the body of `pirateDef`.

Let's talk about the lines of that in turn:

```
def pirateDef(inputList = list()):
```

First, the name is terrible. A function name should generally indicate what the function does, and never have "def" in it. Secondly, the parameter list `(inputList = list())` specifies that at *function creation time* python should create one specific list object, and assign it to the variable `inputList`. If your function modifies `inputList`, those modifications will persist across invocations to the function `pirateDef`.

The normal thing is to use something immutable, usually `None`, and test for that inside the function itself.

```
# prepare query 
col = mongoConnect().MYCOL
# query for pirates Arrrr
pirates = col.find({ "_id" : {"$in" : inputList}}
                      ).sort("_id",1).limit(50)
```

I know nothing of mongo, so I have no comment on these lines.

```
# loop over users
userList = list()
for person in pirates:
    # do stuff that has nothing to do with the problem

       # append user to userlist
    userList.append(person)
```

These lines are equivalent to `userList = list(pirates)`.

```
return userList
```

Given that you did nothing with `userList`, you could just have returned `list(pirates)`. But given that you did nothing with `pirates` other than retrieve it, you could just have returned that.

Accordingly, your function would become:

```
def pirateDef(inputList = None):
    if not inputList:
       inputList = []
    # prepare query 
    col = mongoConnect().MYCOL
    # query for pirates Arrrr
    return col.find({ "_id" : {"$in" : inputList}}
                          ).sort("_id",1).limit(50)
```

I realise that probably doesn't solve your problem, which is no doubt something to do with how you query mongo.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for my bad example. I had to rewrite everything to apply it online, so there are terrible names and some of my stuff does not make sense cause I deleted alot of stuff. Turned out the Error was in my query (my DB was not matching the inputs I gave, so basically my code made everything right...). Thank you very much for trying to help me out!